# Odd behaviour in java recursion example

Tags: java, recursion

I have following program to get the sum of array elements using recursion.

```
public class ArraySum {

int sum = 0;

private int sum(int[] array, int index) {

    if (index + 1 == array.length) {
        return array[index];
    }

    sum += (array[index] + sum(array, index + 1));

    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    ArraySum arraySum = new ArraySum();
    arraySum.sum(array, 0);
    System.out.println(arraySum.sum);
}
}
```

I am getting the wrong output in above code.

**Output : 1** (which is first element of array)

Now when I divide the addition operation in two different statements, I get the right output,

`sum += (array[index] + sum(array, index + 1));`

**CHANGED TO**

`int currentSum = (array[index] + sum(array, index + 1));`
   `sum += currentSum;`

**New output is : 15** (which is correct).

Can someone explain the reason behind this?

NOTE that I am returning zero from the function but I am storing sum in class member `sum`.

Comment: Congratulations!  You've just demonstrated why you shouldn't rely on side-effects to make your method work.

Comment: Are you sure those methods should `return 0` ?

Comment: @Berger, I am returning zero but the sum is stored in class member `sum` and I am printing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your general approach to recursion: you are trying it with a method that is not re-entrant, which is always a danger.

The method is not re-entrant because field `sum` is shared across all invocations of `sum` and `sum1` on the same object of `Test`, and it is never reset to zero (which is what causes the incorrect behavior that you are observing).

A proper way to fix this is to delete `sum` field, and instead return `sum`, not zero, from `sum1`:

```
private int sum1(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index == array.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    return array[index] + sum1(array, index + 1);
}

public int sum(int[] array) {
    return sum1(array, 0);
}
```

Comment: `sum` was shared between the functions but I was not running both the functions back to back. I was only calling one function in one execution of program and then I was calling another function after editing the code accordingly. Now I have updated the question to provide more clarification.

Comment: @Rahulkhandelwal You get wrong behavior because your recursive function returns zero, not the sum, for all elements, except the base case, which relies on the previous element to do the addition (try calling your function with a single-element array, it will always print zero, even after your modification). If you want to see what's going on, step through your code with a debugger. If you want to fix the problem, change to a correct recursive implementation above.